# How to get an name from the multiple selected object in checkboxes in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a scenario where i want to get the name from the multiple selected checked boxes and display divs based on the selected checkbox.

Issue: I have 4 checkboxes and and I want to display divs based n the selected checkbox. these checkboxes are multiple, so can select multiple checkbox and get the multiple ids.

Here is the HTML code that I have done to achieve it:

```
             <b-row>
                <div v-for="services in getServices" :key="services.id">
                  
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    multiple
                    :name="services.name"
                    v-model="selected"
                    :value="{ name: services.name, id: services.id }"

                  />
                  <label :for="services.name">{{ services.name }}</label>
                </div>
               
              </b-row>
                {{selected}}
```

i have this also in the script side:

```
return {
    selected: [],
}
```

Current issue:

I cannot get only id /name in the `selected` section. if I can get it , I can show the divs based on that. but I need to have the ids also while I want to save/post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the checkbox to only name or id as follows for example and base it on that

```
 <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    multiple
                    :name="services.name"
                    v-model="selected"
                    :value="services.id"

                  />
<div v-if="getNameFromId(selected[0]) == 'div1'">This is div1.</div>

methods: {
  getNameFromId: function (id) {
    return this.getServices.find(service => service.id === id).name;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply, actually i want to show the div based in the name and save it later using the id.

Comment: You can create a computed property or a filter that returns the name from the id

Comment: how to do that? create computed property / filter

Comment: Can you show me how are you showing the divs? to help you better

Comment: to show the divs i am doing this : 
```<div
v-if="selected.name == 'div1'">This is div1.</div>```

Comment: Check the answer i edited it to show you how you can get the name from the id but pay attention that selected is an array not an object

Comment: it says now ```'getServices' is not defined ``` but I have already mentioned in the method like this: ```getServices: [], services: [],```

Comment: To access it use this.getServices, it's in data right?

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to array:

```
<div v-for="service in services" :key="service.id">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    multiple
    :name="service.name"
    v-model="service.selected"
    :value="{ name: service.name, id: service.id }"
  />
  <label :for="services.name">{{ service.name }}</label>
</div>
{{ selectedServices }}
```

And in the script:

```
export default {
  name: "component",
  data: function () {
    return {
      selected: [],
      services: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Pedro",
          selected: false,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Jose",
          selected: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    selectedServices: function () {
      return this.services.filter((item) => item.selected);
    },
  },
};
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: if i check on the pedro this comes: ```[ { "id": 1, "name": "Pedro", "selected": true } ]```, but if I want to have just name

Comment: Try with:
selectedServices: function () {
      return this.services.filter((item) => item.selected)
              .map(item => item.name);
    },

Comment: okay this is a bit helpful, but this is the issue that if I select both pedro and jose, my both div is not coming out. only one is showing. 
i am using this for the two div:
```<div  
v-if="selectedServices == 'pedro'">
show pedro
</div>
<div  
v-if="selectedServices == 'jose'">
show jose
</div>``` 
@alpachino

Comment: You can created a method wich return if name is in the selected array and use this method in the v-if. I have updated the CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-black-9u301